# STR instruction 'fails' in Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm, keil

I have written this piece of code that implements Bubble Sort in assembly. I declared an unsorted array with 10 elements with the DCD directive and then I have made register R0 indicate to the first element of this array. Then I implemented the Bubble Sort as below:

```
; Bubble Sort algorithm in Assembly ;)

            AREA    BubbleSort, CODE, READONLY
            ENTRY
            EXPORT  __main
            GLOBAL  bsort 
                
__main

bsort
               ;Bubble sort that works on 32bit integers
               ;R0 = array location, R1 = array size
               
               ;ADRL  R0, Vals                        ;R0 - array location
               LDR    R0, =ARRAY
               MOV    R1, #Size
            
bsort_next
               MOV    R2, #0                        ;current element number
               MOV    R6, #0                        ;number of swaps
            
bsort_loop
               ADD    R3, R2, #1                    ;R3 = next element number
               CMP    R3, R1                        ;check for the end of the array(R1 = size)
               BGE    bsort_check                   ;when we reach for the end check for changes
               LDR    R4, [R0, R2, LSL #2]          ;R4 = current element value
               LDR    R5, [R0, R3, LSL #2]          ;R5 = next element value
               CMP    R4, R5                        ;Compare element values
               STRGT  R5,[R0,R2,LSL #2]             ;If R4 > R5, store current value at next
               STRGT  R4,[R0,R3,LSL #2]             ;If R4 > R5, Store next value at current
               ADDGT  R6, R6, #1                    ;increment swap counter
               MOV    R2, R3                        ;advance to the next element
               B      bsort_loop

bsort_check
               CMP    R6, #0                        ;Check the swap counter - check if there were swaps this iteration
               SUBGT  R1, R1, #1                    ;Optimization: skip last value in the next loop
               BGT    bsort_next                    ;If there were changes do it again else return

Stop           B       Stop

;Define size constant
Size           EQU   10
ARRAY          DCD    9, 1, 3, 5, 6, 4, 2, 7, 8, 0      
END
    
    
;The array
;              AREA   UNSORTEDARRAY, DATA, READWRITE
;             ALIGN
;ARRAY        DCD    0, 1, 3, 5, 2, 4, 6, 7, 8, 9   
;              END
```

I can see the array I have declared in SRAM with the values I have given it once I start stepping through the code.

As you can see I store the values for the current and next element in R4 and R5 registers so I can compare them.

Right below that line I compare the two and attempt to do a swap if current>next:

In the first iteration for example current(R4) is 9 and next(R5) is 1 so there should be a swap. The STRGTs below the compare execute however when I look at the RAM in the memory window nothing is changed there. I was expecting to see the swap on the memory itself but the contents of the memory stays the same .Basically no swap takes place into the memory itself even tough the two conditional STR instructions get executed.

Can someone please help me understand why this is happening so I can fix the issue? Thank you for reading!

Some remarks:

- I have initially declared the array in a separate DATA  section but I could not even see it as initialized with the memory window. I did some reading and I found out  that happens because I have not written a piece of code that would copy that array from the FLASH and store it into RAM so I have declared the array into the CODE section so I can see it with the debugger.
- I'm not using any hardware I'm using the simulator in keil for this exercise. Not sure if that is problematic or not.

Comment: `AREA    BubbleSort, CODE, READONLY`, well, that's read only. You do need to put your stuff into a writable data area. Not sure how the keil simulator handles protection, but it may just silently ignore your stores which matches what you observe. Under a real OS your program would crash.

Comment: @Jester thanks for your answer.
I have tried to modify the CODE to be readwrite'able and in that case the memory where I store the array is full of 0's. 

I have also tried to modify the code and make a DATA AREA which is READWRITE and the memory there is still initialized to 0 :((.